# Adding members via Channel Form

Tags: zoo-visitor, member-management

We want to allow our members to add (aka "register") their team members as users on our website with their own login information.  The new user should be linked to their company (currently a Playa field in the CMS) and be added to the "Team Member" member group (versus the Manager group that they are in).  The newly added team member will then be able to go and edit their information.  And ideally the manager would be able to remove the team member should they leave the company.

Just curious if anyone else has done anything like this, or has any thoughts on the best way to move forward with this.  We are currently running EE 2.9.2 and using Zoo Visitor 1.3.34.

Comment: I've done almost exactly this before. It's all perfectly possible, but if you want to create a secure system with a good user experience you'll probably need a few custom functions to tie everything together. My system relied heavily on Channel Form, Playa, Profile:Edit and Postmaster (for emails), but with a custom add-on to fill in the gaps. (These days you should really be using the native relationships functionality instead of Playa though). Don't underestimate this - it has hidden depths that are easy to overlook.

Comment: Thanks James.  Can you elaborate on the "create secure system"?  For this particular application, the only people who would be allowed to add members via Channel Forms are our members who pay for access.  And thanks for the tip on using the native relationships vs Playa. I'm trying to look to the future for possible EE3 upgrade, and am trying to simplify as much as possible.

Comment: The security aspect I was thinking about was avoiding having account passwords flying about over email, so I created a little invitation system off the back of a Channel Form submission, which creates a member, assigning them a random password, then emails them an activation code and the opportunity to set their password. I also created "Bankcracker" as part of that, allowing multiple channel entries to be created in a single Channel Form submission, though that might not be relevant to your situation https://github.com/thisisjamessmith/Bankcracker

Comment: Ahhh, gotcha.  Yeah, that would be great for the registration part. Is that something you would be willing to share/sell?  And thanks for Bankcracker.  Not relevant in this particular situation but I can see it being useful!